# Connecting Google Cloud Memorystore with App Engine service

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, node-redis, google-cloud-memorystore

I'm currently trying to connect my App Engine node.js service to a Google Cloud Memorystore. 
Following this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-flex), I need both to run in the same network and region (in my case Europe). This seems impossible since I can only create the Redis instance in *europe-west-1* or *europe-west-4*, while App Engine offers me *europe-west*, *europe-west-2* or *europe-west-3*.

I'm assuming 'same region' stands for *europe-west-x* ? If this is true, I'm still unable to connect, configuring the Node.js on the IP `X.X.X.X:XXXX` as described in the gcloud console (for my active Redis instance) the app throws connection failed, `ETIMEDOUT`.

Is the region the reason?

The instance has the authorized network set to `default` and the apps *app.yaml* has:

`network: 
 name: default`

UPDATE:

Even when i have GAE in *europe-west-1* and Memorystor in *europe-west* as suggested i get

> Redis connection to X.X.X.X:XXXX failed - connect ETIMEDOUT
>   X.X.X.X:XXXX

I'm using [node_redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis) with the following code fragment to test the connection (REDIS_PORT  and REDIS_IP are the values i see on the Memorystore instance page):

```
const redis = require('redis'); 
let redisClient = redis.createClient(REDIS_PORT, REDIS_IP);

redisClient.set("string key", "string val", redis.print);
redisClient.hset("hash key", "hashtest 1", "some value", redis.print);
redisClient.hset(["hash key", "hashtest 2", "some other value"], redis.print);
redisClient.hkeys("hash key", function (err, replies) {
    console.log(replies.length + " replies:");
    replies.forEach(function (reply, i) {
        console.log("    " + i + ": " + reply);
    });
    redisClient.quit();
});
redisClient.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("Redis rror " + err);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized the GAE service has to run in the flex environment, so the application is based on *Google Compute Engine* aswell. The `env: flex` was missing in the app.yaml. The communication between GAE and Memorystore is working with this configuration.

Answer (score 2):

**Regions** are specific geographical locations, and each region has different **zones** (or just one). For example, *europe-west1-b* and *europe-west1-c* are the same region (europe-west1) but different zone (*b* or *c*).

Also, *europe-west1* and *europe-west2* are different regions the same way *europe-west1* and *us-central1* are.

Regarding your issue, ***europe-west* is the same as *europe-west1***, so you should choose that for connecting GAE to Memorystore. If you choose two different "numbers" for regions, as they are different regions, you won't be able to connect.

Here is a piece of documentation that explains "[**Regions and zones**](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/)":

> - Regions are collections of zones. Zones have high-bandwidth, low-latency network connections to other zones in the same region. [...]
> - A zone is an isolated location within a region. The fully-qualified name for a zone is made up of `region`-`zone`. [...]

Comment: And how do i choose the same number if the list only offers me eu-west, eu-west2 and eu-west3 for GAE and eu-west1 and eu-west4 for Memorystore ? There is no intersection in the set of numbers i can choose...

Comment: oh, sorry! I just edited the answer, (in the bolt section) I meant that "europe-west1" is the same as "europe-west". (I wrote europe-west in both)